# Filter Input type number using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, numbers

How do I not allowed when typing **"2"** when **first typing**?
Is possible using JavaScript?

```
<input type="number"/>
```

Only "2" can not typing when start.
Any body help? Thank you.

Comment: You can use regExp and attach it on keydown event while listening for num key 2 (various key code: https://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/15/javascript-char-codes-key-codes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$('input').keypress(function(evt) {
  if (evt.which == "2".charCodeAt(0) && $(this).val().trim() == "") {
    return false;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number"/>
```

Comment: Thank you for help @Amadan :)

Comment: Well it's an overkill (and not little one) to get jQuery just to attach evet and get value from element.
Instead of `$('input')` use `document.querySelector`, instead of  `keypress` use `addEventListener('keypress'`. Instead of `$(this).val()` use `this.value` and You are good to go. I've just saved You a whole lib of unecessary (in Your case) code. What's more, on each call of `$(this)` You would have been creating an new jQuery object instance - instead of just simply getting value from element property.

Comment: @grzesiekgs: OP specified [tag:jquery] in his tags, I answered with jQuery. I assume this is not the only thing he has in his project, and it is weird to mix styles. If that tag were not there, I would have answered with plain JS.

Comment: True that, missed the jQuery part! Still, just for hes information - jQuery is just optional.